# Can this game end in a draw?

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

We have this game:[image]

Clarifications:

- Pawns can move and take across sides.
- Pawns can't jump over other pieces when moving by two squares.
- "Forward" means from the middle of your side towards the middle of your opponent's side, therefore, the middle pawn can initially move in all four directions, but can never return to its starting square once it has been moved.
- A pawn can move two spaces multiple times provided it is still on its starting side.
- En passant is not allowed

Is there a position on the cube, in which the game inevitably leads to a draw (none of the players can win) if both players play perfectly?

Comment: The third rule applies only if the first of these two spaces is empty, right?

Comment: yes, I will add some clarifications to the rules, thanks

Comment: If a pawn is on its starting side, can it move two squares in any of the four directions (as long as it's not blocked)?

Comment: Arthur: yes, if it is in the corner, two of the directions are "forward" and the other two are "sideways". However, if it is next to the middle of an edge, one direction is "forward", two are sideways and the fourth one is pointing towards the centre (backwards), so not allowed.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand the movement rules near edges, but that aside: I don't see any mention of the result if it's my turn and I have no valid moves. Do I lose, or is it a draw?

Comment: Peter Taylor: interesting idea, stalemate would probably be a draw if the other opponent was silly enough to let that happen. But assuming stalemate isn't a draw (person on turn loses), is there a drawing position?